# counting occurrence of 2d array in java

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

This is the question i am trying to solve:

Write a class called `ArrayHistogram`, which contains a main method and a static method called histogram, which has the following signature:
`public static int[] histogram(int[][] arrayA)`
In the main method, declare and initialize a two dimensional array, call it `arrayA`. This array must contain some non-negative integer numbers. The histogram method accepts `arrayA` and puts the frequency of occurrence of elements of `arrayA` into a one dimensional array (`histA`) and returns `histA`. Frequency of occurrence means, the number of times an element occurs in the array. Your program should work for a ragged array, as well. Your program should determine the size of the `histA` automatically, before declaring the variable `histA`.

Hint: Figure 1 shows a sample 2D array(`arrayA`) and the corresponding `histA`. `histA[0] = 2` shows that 0 occurred twice in A. Or, `histA[3] = 1`, shows that number 3 appeared once in A.

I have done this so far

```
public class ArrayHistogram
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        // declearing and initializing a 2D array.
        int [][] arrayA = {{5,8,8,4,3},{1,4,2,2,3},{7,4,6,6,9}};
        histogram(arrayA);

    }
    public static int[] histogram (int [][] arrayA)
    {  // nested for loop to go through the array.
        int max = 0;
       for ( int row = 0; row<arrayA.length; row++){
           for ( int col=0; col < arrayA[row].length; col++){

               if ( arrayA[row][col]> max ){
                   max = arrayA[row][col];
            }
        }
    }
    int histA[] = new int [max];
    for ( int row = 0; row<arrayA.length; row++){
           for ( int col=0; col < arrayA[row].length; col++){
               histA[arrayA[row][col]]++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(histA);
        return histA;
    }
}
```

This line:

```
histA[arrayA[row][col]]++;
```

shows a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

First am I doing this right?

If not how should I make it happen?

Comment: *"shows a java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception"*  I suspect you mean an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  Please copy/paste this type of information (the stack trace), and [edit it into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14617900/edit) using code formatting.  Also, to make text more clear for the reader, use upper case for the start of every sentence, the word I, proper names like Java..

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that arrays are indexed starting at `0`, so your `max` value is not going to be an index available in your `histA` array. One way to fix this is create your array like so:

```
int histA[] = new int[max + 1];
```

In your second loop, when you hit `row` being `2` and `col` being `4` it's going to attempt to use `histA[9]` which isn't a valid index in that array unless you define your array to be of size `10`, which in your case is `max + 1`.

Comment: i did that and wanted to print the array after doing that and the array prints like this : [I@4cce3393
why ?

Comment: When you call `System.out.println()` and pass in an array, the print out ends up giving you the memory address of the array. If you want to print out the array elements, you'll need to iterate over that array and print each element out. Like: `for (int x = 0; x < histA.length; x++) { System.out.println(histA[x]); }`

Answer (score 0):

`length` is an attribute of array objects which returns the size. Now since you are looping your array starting from 0 to the `length` of array, its referring to the index of array which doesn't even exists. Hence an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

Just update your `for` loop termination expression to `arrayA.length-1` and `arrayA[row].length-1` and it will all be working fine.

Also for all such `exceptions` just check their [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) and you will get your answer.

Comment: Welcome @SulaimanAlyahya ! And yes, whenever you ask some question on SO, don't forget to accept the answer which worked for you.